# What does parameter1 0x4 for bugcheckcode 0x122 mean?

Tags: windows-10, bsod, debug, documentation

I've got a bsod (on windows 10.0.14393.0) and trying to figure out what happened. Event log says

```
bugcheckcode 122
bugcheckparameter1 0x4
bugcheckparameter2 0x0
bugcheckparameter3 0xffff8406530bf010
bugcheckparameter4 0xa782390
```

but I'm already stuck at `parameter1` since when I looked at the corresponding [bug check code reference page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff557313(v=vs.85).aspx), there they only have listed `parameter1` values `0x1`, `0x2`, `0x5`, `0x6`, `0x7`, `0x8`, `0x9`, `0xA` and `0xB`.

Does anybody know where to find information about `parameter1` value `0x4`?

**Later**

Following suggestion in a comment by [Jamie Hanrahan](https://superuser.com/users/348119/jamie-hanrahan) I am adding a link to the memory dump file [dump.zip](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz5n7ThWFJHOZHcwczI1cllKSnc).

Comment: This type of crash can be caused by many things.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Ramhound Just starting investigation. These codes all mean something,  for starters I want to know how to find out what does mine mean.

Comment: Btw before that I had `bugcheckcode 190` and this one is not on the list at all.

Comment: What tool did you use to determine that parameter1 was equal to 0x4?

Comment: @Ramhound looked into event viewer

Comment: There should be a crash dump file generated, you need to debug the dump file...  http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5558-windbg-basics-debugging-crash-dumps-windows-10-a.html

Comment: @Moab Thanks, this is certainly useful, will try. But the question is mainly about where to find information on these codes missing at the Microsoft pages

Comment: This value is not documented even in the latest version of windbg.

Comment: If it isn't documented in the windbg help (and David Marshall is correct: It isn't) then there likely is no official source. It's barely possible that there's an MSDN page or something similar that describes it. But further info can still be had by using windbg on the minidump file. If this is beyond your skills, please upload your minidump to a file sharing service and post its location as an edit to this question. A kernel memory dump would be even better - enable this in Control Panel | System and Security | System | Advanced System Settings | Advanced | Startup and Recovery

Comment: Bugcheck code 0x122 in general, regardless of parameter1, means _"This bug check indicates that an internal error in the Windows Hardware Error Architecture (WHEA) has occurred. Errors can result from a bug in the implementation of a platform-specific hardware error driver (PSHED) plug-in supplied by a vendor, the firmware implementation of error records, or the firmware implementation of error injection."_ The thing that stands out here is "hardware error". These usually come from problems with the CPU, the chipset, etc. There is a good possibility that a "machine check exception" occurred.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Many thanks for the suggestion, I have added a link to the dump file.

Comment: 122 is decimal and turns in 0x7A (KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR).

Comment: @magicandre1981 Oh I see! Indeed there was something about power kernel said in the event viewer. Could you please make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake. The 122 is decimal. The hex value is 0x7A. The 0x7A stands for [Bug Check 0x7A: KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> The KERNEL_DATA_INPAGE_ERROR bug check has a value of 0x0000007A. This
>   bug check indicates that the requested page of kernel data from the
>   paging file could not be read into memory.

Comment: Ah, oops! However the description quoted is incorrect. You can get "inpage errors" from any mapped file, not just the pagefile. These are usually IME caused by disk read errors, but further looking at the dump suggests a deeper problem: corruption of Mm data structures. I'd be running a memory test.